# Class diagram (Object oriented programming)

Tags: python, loops, class, oop

I have this program.

```
class Rocket():
        def __init__(self, name) 
             self.name=name
             self.height=0
        def moveUp(self) 
             self.height+=1
myRockets=["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" ] 
fleetOfRockets=[]
for rocket in myRockets: 
 fleetOfRockets.append(Rocket(rocket))
for rocket in fleetOfRockets:
   print(rocket.name, rocket.height)
```

and the output of this is like this;

```
One 0
Two 0
Three 0
Four 0
Five 0
```

and I want to do in here is that I want each rocket will be move up by 10.
Here is what output that I want.

```
One 10
Two 20
Three 30
Four 40
Five 50
```

I don't know how to do this without changing anything in the class Rocket.

Comment: Loop on the rockets, and loop to call each rocket's `moveUp` ten times.

Comment: `for rocket in fleetOfRockets:` then `rocket.moveUp()`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are only allowed to change the code outside of the class declaration.

There is a myriad of ways you can get that output depending on what you want to achieve.

You could enumerate the rockets in the first loop and directly assign to height:

```
myRockets=["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" ] 
fleetOfRockets=[]

for i, rocket in enumerate(myRockets, 1):
    new_rocket = Rocket(rocket)
    new_rocket.height = i * 10
    fleetOfRockets.append(new_rocket)
```

You can also create an inner loop to call `moveUp` instead of directly setting `height`.

Comment: how can create that inner loop to call the ```moveUp```

Comment: @Apple That’s something you can easily figure out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change anything in your Rocket class, you could put a final height in the myRockets list. So:

```
    myRockets = [["One", 10], ["Two", 20], ["Three", 30], ["Four", 40], ["Five", 50]]
```

And when you want to append to the fleetOfRockets, you can use the index to access each value. However, this means that the fleetOfRockets list stores a bunch of lists, and not each individual rocket (so you have to type out the list and index every time you access it):

```
    for rocket in myRockets:
        fleetOfRockets.append([Rocket(rocket[0]), rocket[1]])
```

Then, you can use a for loop and access the final height of the rocket to loop through that many times. For example:

```
    for rocket in fleetOfRockets:
        for i in range(0, rocket[1]):
            rocket[0].moveUp()
```

However, it could be simpler to add a final_height in your Rocket class (so that the information can be stored more easily, in one class), *then* to substitute the final height in the for loop with `rocket.final_height`. This way, you don't have to use the list and index every time you want to access a piece of information.